add date as suffix to column name in R
I am creating a new variable based on some conditions
like
mr_data$flag <- ifelse(is.na(mr_Data$age),1,0) 
however i want to create a variable with the system date like
mr_data$flag_2024-08-20 <- ifelse(is.na(mr_Data$age),1,0) 
so wondering what is the best way to do this.
mr_data$flag_Sys.date() <- ifelse(is.na(mr_Data$age),1,0) 

Here are a few ways using the built-in BOD data frame.  They are all non-destructive, i.e. they output a new data frame with the new column so that the original is preserved.  The first three are more pipe friendly because they only use BOD once.  In the second solution the name junk is ignored and the name that is set is used instead.  All of them use new_name defined at the top.  We separate the definition of new_name out here to make the code easier to read.  Alternately the new name expression could be inserted inline (except for 3).
new_name <- paste0("flag_", Sys.Date()) 

# 1
BOD |> 
  within(assign(new_name, +is.na(Time)))

# 2
BOD |> 
  transform(junk = +is.na(Time) |> data.frame() |> setNames(new_name))

# 3
library(dplyr)
BOD |>
  mutate({{new_name}} := +is.na(Time))

# 4
replace(BOD, new_name, +is.na(BOD$Time))


Follow these steps.

Compose the new variable name with paste0.
Then optionally replace "-" by "_". To run this part of the code uncomment after paste0.
Finally, to create the column use [[ instead of $.

Note also that I do not use ifelse. When the result is a binary 0/1, the logical condition can be directly coerced to integer with an arithmetic operation. And FALSE/TRUE become 0/1.
flag <- paste0("flag_", Sys.Date()) #|> gsub("-", "_", x = _)
mr_data[[flag]] <- +is.na(mr_data$age)
mr_data
#>    age flag_2024_08_20
#> 1   22               0
#> 2   NA               1
#> 3   NA               1
#> 4   24               0
#> 5   21               0
#> 6   NA               1
#> 7   21               0
#> 8   22               0
#> 9   22               0
#> 10  NA               1
#> 11  23               0
#> 12  NA               1
#> 13  24               0
#> 14  22               0
#> 15  22               0
#> 16  24               0
#> 17  22               0
#> 18  22               0
#> 19  NA               1
#> 20  21               0

Created on 2024-08-20 with reprex v2.1.0

Data creation code
set.seed(2024)
mr_data <- data.frame(age = sample(c(21:24, NA_integer_), 20L, TRUE))

Created on 2024-08-20 with reprex v2.1.0

You could also doing this by setting the date a variable and then using separate_wider from dplyr to create the new column, a nice advatage of this is that if you have multiple dates you will get a flag column for each date:
mr_data$id <- 1:nrow(mr_data)


mr_data_wide <- mr_data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = flag, names_prefix = "flag_")

mr_data_wide

